# vector space R³

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Determining the three vectors are linearly dependent or independent
>   $$u = (1, 2, -3), v = (3, 1, -2), w =(5, -5, 6). $$

**Is looking through determinant enough to check whether linearly dependent or independent?**

[image]

I know that determinant of the matrix is zero. So, Can I say it is linearly independent because of that determinant is zero ? To find the relation between $u$, $v$, and $w$ we look for constants a, b, and c. When I apply the echelon form I get  $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -4\\0& 1 & 3\\0 &0 &0\end{bmatrix}$. Up to here I understand, but I'm stuck here

[image]

how can we select $c = 1$ ? How come $b = -3c$ and $a = -3b - 5c $ ? Written $u$, $v$, and $w$ are linearly independent. But, the determinant is zero? I'm confused.

Comment: From echelon form you got, it follows that $a - 4c = 0$ and $b + 3c = 0$, while $c$ can be arbitrary (say, $1$). Since $4u - 3v + w = 0$, $u, v$ and $w$ are NOT linearly independent.

Comment: thank you I got @Zhanxiong. is looking through determinant enough to check whether linearly dependent or independent?

Comment: Yes, but it is not always easier than getting the echelon form.

Comment: The determinant is enough in this case.  But it only works when you have $n$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$.  If you have more or less then the matrix you'll construct won't be square and determinants aren't defined.  Also the determinant won't tell you *how many* of the vectors are linear combinations of the others.  So in this case, calculating the determinant is enough to tell you that these vectors are linearly dependent, but if in your future problems you want *more* info than that, or you don't have $n$ vectors, then just use row reduction.

Comment: Do you mean sometimes getting echelon is easier than getting determinant? @Zhanxiong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ the following statements are equivalent:

- $A$ is invertible
- the columns of $A$ are linearly independent
- the rows of $A$ are linearly independent
- the rank of $A$ is $n$
- the determinant of $A$ is nonzero

So the answer to your question is yes, we need only check the determinant of 
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&5\\
2&1&-5\\
-3&-2&6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is zero to prove that the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent. Here,
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&5\\
2&1&-5\\
-3&-2&6
\end{bmatrix}
=0
$$
so the columns are indeed linearly dependent.

Alternatively we can use the fact that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&5\\
2&1&-5\\
-3&-2&6
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-4\\
0&1&3\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to deduce that $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)=2<3$ so the columns of $A$ must be linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You have some special vectors $u$, $v$, and $w$ that their linear dependence or independence is of interest. Let us put each of them into the **rows** of a matrix so that we have

$${\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
u\\
v\\
w
\end{array}} \right]_{3 \times 3}} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2&{ - 3}\\
3&1&{ - 2}\\
5&{ - 5}&6
\end{array}} \right]$$

Now do the elementary row operations (ERO) to get the **echelon** form:

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2&{ - 3}\\
0&{ - 5}&7\\
0&0&0
\end{array}} \right]$$

Now can you tell me that what a **zero row** means? We did ERO which means we just computed some linear combinations of the vectors and we ended up we zero vector! Yes! This means that your vectors are linearly **dependent**.